# Foreign key constraint failed - sql database inserting into table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

Does anyone know whats wrong with the foreign keys in this table (appointments).

It won't let me insert this line into the table:

```
INSERT INTO Appointments 
VALUES (765, 'D901', 'W011', '8/10/2022', '15:00', 37, 25.50);
```

I get this error:

> Error while executing SQL query on database 'Dogdaycare database': FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

These are the individual tables:

[Dogs table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9jsB.png)

[Owners table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz2v5.png)

[Grooming table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0XrL.png).

This is the SQL to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Owners
(
    ownerID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ownerName CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    telNo VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Dogs
(
    dogID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ownerID INT NOT NULL,
    dogName CHAR(50),
    breed CHAR(50),
    size CHAR(10),
    coat CHAR(50),
    comments CHAR(250),
    FOREIGN KEY (ownerID) REFERENCES Owners(ownerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Grooming
(
    groomOption VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    description CHAR(200),
    groomTime INT NOT NULL,
    groomCost INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Appointments
(
    ownerID INT NOT NULL,
    dogID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    groomOption VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    bookingDate DATE NOT NULL,
    bookingTime VARCHAR(10),
    TOTALLengthOfAppointment REAL NOT NULL,
    TOTALCost REAL NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY(ownerID) REFERENCES Owners(ownerID),
    FOREIGN KEY(dogID) REFERENCES Dogs(dogID),
    FOREIGN KEY(groomOption) REFERENCES Grooming(groomOption)
);
```

Comment: For Grooming is it `W011` or `WO11` in the table? is it a zero or a capital o

Comment: Please don’t link to images, instead add all information directly to your question as editable text. This is generally good practice but also in your specific case it would make it easy to determine if your data contained a zero or a O - something we can’t do from an image